# How to link opencv to ROS indigo (catkin) with CMake (ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: ros, opencv, catkin, linking, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Am so far not able to use cv_bridge. Am getting this compilation error

```
Make Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake:106 (message):
  Project 'cv_bridge' specifies '/usr/include/opencv' as an include dir,
  which is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '/opt/ros/indigo//usr/include/opencv'.  Ask the maintainer ..
```

May be the problem in my CMake (...?)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(XY)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
cv_bridge
image_transport
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
)

#set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/lib/opencv")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc highgui PATHS /home/polar/soft/lib/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/cmake)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

if(OpenCV_FOUND)
# include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("\n\n OpenCV found!!!! \n\n")   
endif()
```

Any idea on the cause of the problem and how to solve it please? I was using ROS fuerte in the past and never experienced such problems....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234483/how-to-link-opencv-to-ros-indigo-(catkin)-with-cmake-(ubuntu-14.04)?/) by [polar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26882/polar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you have removed OpenCV from the system (there is no folder `/usr/include/opencv` and there should be), and instead you're building your own opencv, as evident by the `PATHS /home/polar/soft/lib/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/cmake` in your `find_package` call.

I'd recommend ensuring OpenCV is installed using `apt-get` and removing the `PATHS /home/polar/soft/lib/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/cmake` from your `find_package` call.

If you need a custom version of OpenCV, then you'll need to rebuild any ROS packages using OpenCV. For example, the `cv_bridge` ROS package you are using depends on OpenCV, and is probably the one contributing the include directory `/usr/include/opencv` which no longer exists since you removed it.

This doesn't have anything to do with Fuerte versus Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1